# Send an email in Perl using sendmail command

Tags: perl, sendmail

I have written a script which needs to send an email to particular user.

Below is the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; 
use warnings;

my $filename = "/usr/people/vkk/Downloads/report_daily_2022_08_30.txt";

my $mailprog='/usr/'.($^O eq 'irix'?'lib':'sbin').'/sendmail';

`echo "Subject:Report" | $mailprog -t $ENV{'USERMAIL'} < $filename `;

print "Done\n";
```

The script works fine, but as I have mentioned *Subject* as an *Report*, this fails to show the subject in the email.

How can I add the Subject in this case?

I don't want to use `mail` command, since attachments are sent as an attached file.

Using `sendmail` attachment are been shown in the message body itself while we open the email. So needed to achieve this in `sendmail` command itself.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/564593/how-to-add-subject-to-sendmail-function)  helps

Comment: This is in perlfaq: [How do I send email?](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq9#How-do-I-send-email?)

Comment: @Jens 'Subject' is not coming up in the email.

Comment: add a blank after `:`

Comment: @TLP I am using Perl 5.16.3, so installing a module is out of the scope in our environment.

Comment: @Jens No luck. It comes as "(No subject)" in subject line :(

Comment: The < has a higher binding precedence than | when the pipeline command for mail is built, hence the echo command is ignored.

Comment: You are basically trying to feed sendmail from two sides, i.e. `echo "subject:..." | sendmail < file`. This makes no sense, there can only be a single feeding from stdin. Either do a `(echo "subject; ...; echo;  cat file)  | sendmail)` or include the mail header in file and just use `sendmail < file`.

Answer (score 2):

Typically you don't want to do these things in backticks. You also said you don't want to use modules.

You can open a pipe and write to it:

```
open my $ph, '|-', $mailprog, '-t', $ENV{'USERMAIL'};
print { $ph } ...stuff...
close $ph or die "Problem with $mailprog: $!";
```

With that, you can print the headers, then feed it the message instead of trying to pipe and redirect in the same shell statement. But this is kinda old school.